# Can I assign subsequent columns of Pandas dataframe to tuple of variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to assign the columns of data frame to variables and I wondered if there's a one-liner to do that. So let's say my data frame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'var1': {0: -3.992865426199777,
  1: -5.959995814732142,
  2: -0.8014242989676339,
  3: -1.294283185686384,
  4: -1.318566458565848},
 'var2': {0: 87.0469970703125,
  1: 69.947998046875,
  2: 67.12300109863281,
  3: 100.9739990234375,
  4: 70.27300262451172}})
```

And I'm seeking for something like:

```
var1, var2 = df[["var1", "var2"]]
```

Which is obviously incorrect. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var1, var2 = df["var1"], df["var2"]
print (var1)
0   -3.992865
1   -5.959996
2   -0.801424
3   -1.294283
4   -1.318566
Name: var1, dtype: float64

print (var2)
0     87.046997
1     69.947998
2     67.123001
3    100.973999
4     70.273003
Name: var2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any shortcut for many columns so that I wouldn't have to specify all the columns on the right side?

Comment: @jakes - hmmm, what is reason for it? It seems [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (but it is possible I am wrong)

Comment: Well, I'm asking mainly for aesthetics and laziness reasons. With two columns the solutions you proposed is neat, but with 20 columns it's cumbersome. Sometimes you can unpack things in Python in really neat way with `*` operator and `zip`. I wondered if one can use that here, possibly converting `df.to_dict()`. But I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: @jakes use the list comprehension on right like `[df[col] for col in df]`.